# TYPO3 doesn't respect field names in JOIN query

Tags: sql, join, typo3

I'm trying to fetch a JOIN query in TYPO3 using `createQuery` and `$query->statement(...)`, but get odd results. Can someone explain to me why TYPO3 doesn't include table names as a prefix to column names in a JOIN query? Does this conflict with the ORM? Can I in anyway speed up a query of multiple 1:N-relations?

Example:

```
SELECT 
  client.name, project.name
FROM 
  client
LEFT JOIN
  project ON project.client = client.uid
```

The PHP code from client repository:

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->statement($statement);
$query->getQuerySettings()->setReturnRawQueryResult(true);
var_dump($query->execute());
```

The result prints out only names of the projects:

```
array (size=294)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'Projectname1' (length=21)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'Projectname2' (length=20)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'Projectname3' (length=32)
```

**EDIT**: This might be standard SQL behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aliases for fields:

```
SELECT 
  client.name client_name, project.name project_name
FROM 
  client
LEFT JOIN
  project ON project.client = client.uid
```

Comment: Yeah. One could even do `client.name AS 'client.name'`. Maybe to ease to object mapping procedure.